# How to retireve data from array php

Tags: php, arrays, key

When i use my code :

The coming data will be like this

```
Array
(
    [name] => Facebook
    [author] => Facebook
    [physicalAddress] => 1 Hacker Way\nMenlo Park, CA 94025
    [supportEmail] => android-support@fb.com
    [supportUrl] => https://www.facebook.com/facebook
    [category] => Social
    [storeCategory] => SOCIAL
    [price] => 0
    [changelog] => &#x2022; Improvements for reliability and speed
    [datePublished] => April 11, 2019
    [datePublishedIso] => 2019-04-11T00:00:00Z
    [fileSize] => Varies with device
    [numDownloads] => 1,000,000,000+
    [versionName] => Varies with device
    [operatingSystems] => Varies with device
    [contentRating] => Parental guidance
)
```

I want to get the data individually

like

name,author,etc

how i can do ?

Comment: this question has already been asked,please do a good research before posting

Comment: For next time, start by doing some proper research before asking. If you just googled on your title, you would have found the answer way faster than it took you to write this question.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty simple. Here is how you do it:

```
<?php

$details = array(
'name' => 'Facebook',
'author' => 'Facebook',
'physicalAddress' => '1 Hacker Way\nMenlo Park, CA 94025',
'supportEmail' => 'android-support@fb.com',
'supportUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/facebook',
'category' => 'Social',
'storeCategory' => 'SOCIAL',
'price' => '0',
'changelog' => '&#x2022; Improvements for reliability and speed',
'datePublished' => 'April 11, 2019',
'datePublishedIso' => '2019-04-11T00:00:00Z',
'fileSize' => 'Varies with device',
'numDownloads' => '1,000,000,000+',
'versionName' => 'Varies with device',
'operatingSystems' => 'Varies with device',
'contentRating' => 'Parental guidance',
);
?>

<p><strong>Name: </strong><?php echo $details['name']; ?></p>
<p><strong>Author: </strong><?=$details['author']; ?></p>
<p><strong>Date Published ISO: </strong><?php echo $details['datePublishedIso']; ?></p>
```